# How to pass params to Android AsnycTaskLoader

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I'm trying to pass params into a AsyncTaskLoader. How do I do that?

Currently, I'm putting what I need to pass in in a separate static class. Anyway around this?

```
public class NewsAsyncTaskLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Content>> {

    private static final DbHelper dbHelper = DbHelperFactory.getDbHelper();

    public FeedAsyncTaskLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Content> loadInBackground() {
        List<Content> contents = DbHelper.getStream(FeedSections.getInstance().getCurrentSection());

        feed.setContents(contents);

        return feed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pass additional parameters into your constructor:

```
public FeedAsyncTaskLoader(Context context, String moreInfo) {
    super(context);
    // Do something with moreInfo
}
```

Comment: I tried that. It works for the first time. So what happens when you want to refresh the data for a 2nd time with a different param? Will does the onCreateLoader gets called again?

Comment: Use [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)'s `restartLoader` method - your `onCreateLoader` will be called each time and give you an opportunity to pass in new parameters.